# Count the number of elements filtered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am building an angular app where I display a list of items which can be filtered by the user.
I would like to know the number of items displayed on the page so I can get more from my database if too many items are filtered.
So far, I have tried to get it like this:

HTML:

```
<article ng-repeat="item in filteredList = (items | filter: myFilter)">
```

But when I try to access `$scope.filteredList.length` in my controller i get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable had not been created when the code got evaluated. You can add a watcher to monitor the value change and then trigger the logic.

```
$scope.$watch("filteredList", function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(newVal !== oldVal){
        console.log($scope.filteredList.length);

        //other logic
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this brings me a lot of error in the console. I get this:Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:

Comment: You need to paste your code since $watch will trigger digest cycle which may not be necessary in your case.